# How to check current font of an HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts, styles

Let's say I have a  element defined with the following style:

```
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
```

Is it possible to detect which of these fonts the browser used to render a text element? (Arial, Verdana or Sans-serif)

Answer (score 0):

Fontface Ninja is the chrome extension, by which you can identify the fonts that web-browser is using. Also you can download the fonts.

Comment: cool, but, is it possible to check the font programmatically? I am looking for a way of doings this by javascript. Thanks